# javascript countdown timer with cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, timer, countdown

I have a countdown timer that will show a target amount to be fundraised like USD1000000 and slowly count backwards to zero over a period of days. I got this snippet:

```
$(function() 
{            
var cnt = 75000000;            
var count = setInterval(function() 
{                
if (cnt > 0) 
{                    
$('#target').html("<span>KSHS</span><strong>" + cnt + " Target </strong>");                    
cnt--;                
}                
else 
{                    
clearInterval(count);                    
$('#target').html("<strong> Target Achieved! </strong>");                
}            
}, 4000);        
});
```

The only problem is that everytime you refresh the page the counter starts again which essentially means it will never end.

I'd like it that a when a user revisits/refreshes the page the counter persists and continues. I've read that javascript cookies can be used for this, just don't know how to implement them, any help?

Comment: New users (and users who delete cookies) will get the same start count...? This is not the way to do it. You should be reading the time from the clock.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this SO answer:

[javascript-cookie-timeout-with-countdown-timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487814/javascript-cookie-timeout-with-countdown-timer)

Comment: Seen that link already, it doesn't describe how to set and retrieve the cookie, that would be really helpful.